# Iframe in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm kinda new to C#, and I will appreciate any help, thanks.

Here's my problem: I created an Iframe but I cannot link it to my sidebar or rather I cannot display another HTML unto my Iframe

Here's my code

```
<header>
    <!-- This is sidebar button along with its contents-->
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <!--Contents of the sidebar-->
        <a class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">X</a>
        <!-- The problem starts here, for I don't know what to put -->

        <!-- Option 1: --> <a href="@Html.ActionLink("Employment","emp")" target="iframe_a"> </a>
        <!-- Option 2: --> <a> @@Html.ActionLink("Employment","emp", new{ target="iframe_a"}) </a>

        <a href="#">Department Module</a>
        <a href="#">Leave Module</a>
        <a href="#">Allowance and Deduction</a>
        <a href="#">Salary Module</a>
        <a href="#">User Accounts</a>
        <a href="#">Reports</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main" class="desHead">
        <a class="openNav" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</a>

        <h1>Payroll System</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: You want to display a new page to your iframe with the click of that link?

Comment: This is not a C# question but rather an HTML question. Also why are putting iframes in the header section of your DOM?

Comment: @JerdineSabio yes, i want to display a new page to my iframe, but i cannot link it to my iframe

Comment: @einarc the iframe is inside the body, inside the header is the sidebar which i would like to link every href to the iframe, but i failed to do so